# XAML List conent from left to right, top to bottom

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, layout, wpf-controls

I am using a WPF user control and a listview which is bound to some items. I would like to display the items in the listview from left to right, and then top to bottom.

So far I have tried to put the code in a WrapPanel which is in a ItemPanel, but this only placed the items horizontally in a line!

```
        <ListView Height="421" Width="500" x:Name="ReportsListBox" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ReportsTemplate}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" MaxWidth="500">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>   
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
```

Anyone know what I should do? I've searched the internet for this, but couldn't find much...

Thanks

Comment: Need more explanation to understand the issue

Comment: So my list box is bound to a number of objects which I would like to be displayed on a Form users to select. I would like to format the listview so the order that items are displayed goes from left to right, and when the item is at then end of the line, the next item would be displayed on the line below. Here is an image to illistrate what I am trying to achieve [link](http://1drv.ms/1uuC7Dj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it looks like you already know, a `WrapPanel` with an `Orientation` of Horizontal will display items from left to right until it reaches the maximum horizontal size of its container, at which point it will wrap down to the next row.

Not sure if this is the issue you are seeing, but a `ListView` has a `ScrollViewer` built in. As such, your `WrapPanel` will never reach the maximum horizontal size if its container, as the `ScrollViewer` will always allow more space.

Try something like this:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

  ...

</ListView>
```

With the horizontal scroll disabled, the `WrapPanel` will be able to reach the maximum width of the container and will wrap as expected.

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks @Simon, that works as expected now! I should have watched out for that HorizontalScrollBarVisibility property